# Display XML correctly in Firefox with Jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, spring-boot

I'm converting a JSON file into an ArrayList and then to XML by using Jackson. It is displayed in Firefox but just as a normal String. By using the inspect element tool I get the whole formatted xml though. Which function can I use to display it correctly on the browser?

My method:

```
private void init() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream is = MyClass[].class.getResourceAsStream("/config/myList.json");
    myList= Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(is, MyClass[].class));
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(); 
    for(MyClass test : myList){
        String asXml += xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(test);
    }
    LOGGER.info("asXml: {}.", asXml);
}
```

Desired output in browser:

```
<myclass xmlns="">
  <myclass>XyClass</ci>
  <myname>XyName</ci>
  ...
</myclass>
```

Actual output: 
    XyClassXyName...

Quite simplified the class looks like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName ="MyClass")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility =     Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyClass {

@XmlElement(required = true) 
private String class;

@XmlElement(required = true)
private String name;
//....

//standard constructor
public MyClass() { } 

public CI(String class, String name){ 
    this.class = class;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getClass() {
    return class;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setClass(String class) {
    this.class = class;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Another weird thing is that I have the exact annotations in another class, trying the same thing with that and there the browser does not display anything... Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Trying to replicate your issue locally. Would you please include your MyClass code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my mistake derived from two things basically. Most important is the definiton of the XML Root Element (not only as annotation in your "MyClass"). Define a global String to create a XML Root element, otherwise your document won't be well-formed and the mistake "junk after document element" will be shown.

```
    private String asXml ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><MyList>";
```

I've adapted the method to:

```
   private void init() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream is = MyClass[].class.getResourceAsStream("/config/myList.json");
myList= Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(is, MyClass[].class));
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(); 
for(MyClass test : myList){
    String asXml += xmlMapper.writer().with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).withRootName("MyClass").writeValueAsString(test);

}
LOGGER.info("asXml: {}.", asXml);
asXml += "</MyList>"; 
}
```

And don't forget to add the correct MediaType in your RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/display", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String getList(Model model) {
    return service.getAsXmlString();
}
```